# Ajax error with django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to activate add to the favorite button with ajax, also the same button should remove from favorite if it is already there, here is my full files:

**models.py**

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete='CASCADE')
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete='CASCADE')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('item', 'user'), )
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:pk>/favorite_item/', views.favorite_item, name='favorite_item'),
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def favorite_item (request, pk):
    favitem = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    data = {
        'is_fav': Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, item=favitem).exists(),
    }

    if data ['is_fav']:
        Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, item=favitem).delete()
    else:
        new_entry = Favorite.objects.create(item=favitem, user=request.user)

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'fostania_web_app/base.html' %}
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    $("#add_to_fav").click(function () {
      console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
              $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("data-favorite_item-url"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_fav) {
            alert('تم');
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

  </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

        {% include 'fostania_web_app/slide.html' %}

 <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <h1 class="my-4" align="right" dir="rtl">إستثمرى فساتينك القديمة مع Fostania</h1>

      <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <h4 class="card-header" align="right">إنشاء حساب جديد</h4>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text" align="center"><img src="{% static 'img/add_user_big.png' %}"><Br>
                  قم بإنشاء حساب جديد على فوستانيا حتى تستطيع عرض الفستان على الموقع</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" align="right">
              <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00a4 , #871f78);border-color: #871f78;">تسجيل حساب جديد</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <h4 class="card-header" align="right">عرض الفستان على الموقع</h4>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text" align="center"><img src="{% static 'img/plus_big.png' %}"><Br>
                  قم بإضافة الفستان مجاناً على الموقع حتى يصل الى مئات المشتريين و المهتمين
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" align="right">
              <a href="{% url 'dress_add' %}" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00a4 , #871f78);border-color: #871f78;">عرض الفستان على الموقع</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <h4 class="card-header" align="right">إبحثى عن الفستان المطلوب</h4>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text" align="center"><img src="{% static 'img/search_big.png' %}"><Br>
                  او يمكن البحث عن الفستان المراد شرائه او تأجيره من وسط مئات الفساتين المعروضة</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" align="right">
              <a href="{% url 'dress_list' %}" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00a4 , #871f78);border-color: #871f78;">إبدأ البحث</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- adsense -->
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Fostania-main -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4202417439740489"
     data-ad-slot="1170851377"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
    <!-- end -->
      <!-- Portfolio Section -->
      <h2 align="right"> اخر الفساتين المضافة للموقع</h2>

      <div class="row">
          {% for dress in dresss %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <div class="card h-100" >
            <a href="{% url 'dress_details' dress.pk%}" align="center"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ dress.dress_image1.url }}" style='width: 200px;height: 200px;' alt=""></a>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title" align="center">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                               {% if user_favs %}
                      {% for item in user_favs %}
                  {% if item.item == dress %}
                                                      <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}" id="add_to_fav">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star-yes.png' %}" title="مسح من  الفساتين المفضلة"></a>
{% else %}

                                <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}" id="add_to_fav">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star_no.png' %}" title="إضافة إلى الفساتين المفضلة"></a>

                          {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                                              <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}" id="add_to_fav">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star_no.png' %}" title="إضافة إلى الفساتين المفضلة"></a>
              {% endif %}
              {% endif %}

                <a href="{% url 'dress_details' dress.pk%}">{{ dress.dress_name }}</a>
                <Br>
                <h3><span class="badge badge-warning">{{ dress.dress_price }} EGP</span></h3>
              </h4>
              <p class="card-text" align="right">
معروض {{ dress.dress_action }} <br>
                  فى محافظة {{ dress.dress_town }}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
      </div>

<!-- paginator part -->
<div align="right">
        {% if dresss.has_previous %}
                        <a href="?page=1"><button class="btn btn-success">&laquo; الأولى </button></a>
            <a href="?page={{ dresss.previous_page_number }}"> <button class="btn btn-success">السابقة</button> </a>
        {% endif %}
</div>
    <div align="center">
        <span class="current" >
            صفحة رقم  {{ dresss.number }} من إجمالى {{ dresss.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
    </div>
    <div align="left">
        {% if dresss.has_next %}
                                    <a href="?page={{ dresss.next_page_number }}"><button class="btn btn-success">التالية</button>  </a>
            <a href="?page={{ dresss.paginator.num_pages }}"><button class="btn btn-success">الاخيرة  &raquo;</button> </a>
                    {% endif %}
</div>


      <!-- paginator part ends -->
    <hr>

      <!-- Call to Action Section -->

    <!-- /.container -->
{% endblock %}
```

And finally it gives me an error

> DoesNotExist at /3/favorite_item/
>   Favorite matching query does not exist.

I made it as normal request which reloads when the user clicks it and it is working perfectly, but i need to Use Ajax to prevent the page from reloading.

Comment: can you show all traceback?

Comment: Looks like it's failing to find the `Favorite` in your DB here: `'is_fav': Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, item=favitem).exists()`. So, an `Item` with `pk=3` exists, but it's failing to find a `Favorite` object associated with it. Is it guaranteed to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `Favorite` doesn't exist for an `Item`, this will raise because you're using `get()`. `get()` raises if an object is not found: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

What I think you want is a combination of `filter()` and `exists()` like this:

```
    data = {
        'is_fav': Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, item=favitem).exists(),
    }
```

Comment: It didn't raise an error but it gave me this `{"is_fav": false}
`, I think the problem is in the ajax script now, I should tell it how to take an action when {"is_fav": false}.. but I don't know how to do it! Also, it is working right with the database . as it inserts a row when it doesn't exist, and deletes it when it is already there! . now all what i need to to stop it from going the url

Comment: So, the switch to `filter()` fixed your `DoesNotExist` error? If so, I'd recommend accepting this answer then creating a new question to address your _new_ issue.

Answer (score 1):

i think that you need to use `POST method` for you ajax call

```
<script>
    $("#add_to_fav").click(function () {
        console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("data-favorite_item-url"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST', # <- here
        ...
    });
});
</script>
```